# Email Server Validation Website

Tags: email, email-server, spf, domainkeys

When sending emails I want my server to have DomainKeys and SPF records setup records correctly, is there a website I can email that does validation of my DomainKeys and SPF records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SPF, Scott Kitterman's tool is the best: http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html.

For DomainKeys, go to http://www.mailradar.com/domainkeys/ - works very well too.

Answer (score 1):

This [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test) should help you.